# Catching exception of camera not avliable in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code to start camera feed with pressing of button:

```
    private void bntStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.Start();
    }
```

In case that the computer doesn't have a camera installed i get auto MSG error:

"an error occured while capturing the video image. The video capture will now be termenated. Object refrence not set to an istance of object"

My goal is to add my own error msg for the user. I tried the following :

```
    private void bntStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
              webcam.Start();
        }
       catch (NullReferenceException exception)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
          return;
       }

    }
```

but nothing happend. any ideas? I tried to debug but on run time it never gets to the catch... maybe wrong exception?

Comment: Have you tried catching `Exception exception` instead of `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Yes.. it still doesn't get to the catch. Is it possible that the auto error msg I'm recciving is not set by exception? i see that the catch block is done and it moved on to the next code.. not jumping to any excption when i sue "step into" with debuging

Comment: Then it seems the class `webcam` is of catches the exception itself. Do you have access to that source code?

Comment: If that's the case, there should be some methods to test for connectivity before you attempt to start the webcam? Can you post a link of the webcam documentation or at least which assemblies you are using?

Comment: i added WebCam_Capture.dll to my project... found it on the internet. here is the link: http://speedy.sh/kznA3/WebCam-Capture.dll

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming webcam.Start() throws a NullReferenceException, which i believe is not the case, you can try to catch the Exception (it's the base exception, but generally not a good practice), inspect the exception type while debugging and catch the actual exception and do what is required

```
private void bntStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        webcam.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change? I replyed to  wudzik that even if i change it to Exception exception it still doesn't work. You are correct that it doesn't throw exception... I know that because i used debugging and 'step into' and no one catch the exception. question is if it's not exception.. where this error coming from? maybe the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception isn't catched, since it probably isn't a `NullReferenceException`, so that could mean webcam isn't equal to null.
You could try catching the error using `Exception`, change your code like this:

```
private void bntStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        webcam.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Something went wrong: {0}", ex.Message));
        return; //Why is this return keyword here?
    }
}
```

Why do you have `return` keyword in your code, while the method is at it's end already? Is this code made simple for posting here? I think it can be removed if so. Has nothing to do with your question tough.

---

It is possible to check for a `NullReferenceException` and an `Exception`, do this with following code:

```
private void bntStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        webcam.Start();
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException nex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("NullReferenceException has been catched: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Something went wrong: {0}", ex.Message));
        return; //Why is this return keyword here?
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work.. it jumps from the end of try to the next code.. jumping over both exceptions.

Comment: @user3463112, So, there is no exception at all. Is it crashing, if so where and could you provide us that code?

Comment: nothing crashes. it present the error then i click ok and i can continue work with other parts of the program.

Comment: i qouted it as it is on the original msg. the error suppose to happen as there are no camera on the pc i ran the program.. my question is how to control the error msg to show what i want rather than the defualt msg.

Comment: Could you change: `MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);` to `MessageBox.Show("Put Custom Error Here");` this will show a custom error.

Answer (score 0):

Is an exception even being thrown? You said you get an error message, but it's not clear from your description that this is actually an exception rather than the webcam library putting up its own messagebox.

If they're handling the error internally themselves and displaying a messagebox, you're out of luck - you can't catch what isn't being caught.

Comment: it doesn't seems like the error msg is from exception... nothing catches it. maybe its from the OP system?

Comment: It won't be the operating system, it will be the webcam library. What I'm saying though is that the webcam library isn't throwing any exception, but is instead detecting its own error and putting up a messagebox. You almost certainly won't have any way of overriding that behaviour, this likely just how the webcam library is designed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is caught and handled by the DLL itself. You're out of luck then. If there's no exception being thrown, there's nothing for you to catch. Unless you get access to the source code of the DLL, you're out of luck.